# can't compile qgis project with codeblocks and vscode ide

Tags: qgis

i want to compile qgis project that i pull it from this url: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS
the problem is that i can't compile it and the ide says that other classes have some bugs,
the error that i receive from my ide is:

```
fatal error: qgstest.h: No such file or directory|
error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope|
qgis\external\astyle\ASLocalizer.cpp|253|error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASLocalizer.cpp|316|error: 'class std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t> > >' has no member named 'emplace_back'|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASLocalizer.cpp||In member function 'std::__cxx11::string astyle::Translation::convertToMultiByte(const wstring&) const':|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASLocalizer.cpp|325|error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\astyle.h|837|warning: identifier 'nullptr' is a keyword in C++11 [-Wc++0x-compat]|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\astyle.h|837|error: 'shared_ptr' has not been declared|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\astyle.h|837|error: expected ',' or '...' before '<' token|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\astyle.h|835|error: default argument missing for parameter 3 of 'std::__cxx11::string astyle::ASFormatter::peekNextText(const string&, bool, int) const'|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASEnhancer.cpp||In member function 'void astyle::ASEnhancer::parseCurrentLine(std::__cxx11::string&, bool, bool)':|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASEnhancer.cpp|627|error: 'class std::vector<astyle::ASEnhancer::SwitchVariables>' has no member named 'emplace_back'|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\astyle.h|837|warning: identifier 'nullptr' is a keyword in C++11 [-Wc++0x-compat]|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\astyle.h|837|error: 'shared_ptr' has not been declared|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\astyle.h|837|error: expected ',' or '...' before '<' token|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\astyle.h|835|error: default argument missing for parameter 3 of 'std::__cxx11::string astyle::ASFormatter::peekNextText(const string&, bool, int) const'|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp||In constructor 'astyle::ASBeautifier::ASBeautifier()':|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp|34|error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp|97|error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp||In member function 'virtual void astyle::ASBeautifier::init(astyle::ASSourceIterator*)':|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp|314|error: 'class std::vector<std::vector<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*>*>' has no member named 'emplace_back'|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp|323|error: 'class std::vector<int>' has no member named 'emplace_back'|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp|327|error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp||In member function 'virtual std::__cxx11::string astyle::ASBeautifier::beautify(const string&)':|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp|905|error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp|1096|error: 'class std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >' has no member named 'emplace_back'|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp||In member function 'void astyle::ASBeautifier::registerContinuationIndent(const string&, int, int, int, int, bool)':|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp|1303|error: 'class std::vector<int>' has no member named 'emplace_back'|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp|1305|error: 'class std::vector<int>' has no member named 'emplace_back'|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp|1311|error: 'class std::vector<int>' has no member named 'emplace_back'|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp|1348|error: 'class std::vector<int>' has no member named 'emplace_back'|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp||In member function 'void astyle::ASBeautifier::registerContinuationIndentColon(const string&, int, int)':|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp|1367|error: 'class std::vector<int>' has no member named 'emplace_back'|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp||In member function 'std::vector<std::vector<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*>*>* astyle::ASBeautifier::copyTempStacks(const astyle::ASBeautifier&) const':|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp|1519|error: 'class std::vector<std::vector<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*>*>' has no member named 'emplace_back'|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp||In member function 'void astyle::ASBeautifier::deleteContainer(T&)':|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp|1547|error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp||In member function 'void astyle::ASBeautifier::deleteBeautifierContainer(std::vector<astyle::ASBeautifier*>*&)':|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp|1563|error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp||In member function 'void astyle::ASBeautifier::deleteTempStacksContainer(std::vector<std::vector<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*>*>*&)':|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp|1584|error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp||In member function 'void astyle::ASBeautifier::initContainer(T&, T)':|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp|1607|error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp||In member function 'void astyle::ASBeautifier::initTempStacksContainer(std::vector<std::vector<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*>*>*&, std::vector<std::vector<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*>*>*)':|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp|1620|error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp||In member function 'void astyle::ASBeautifier::processPreprocessor(const string&, const string&)':|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp|1991|error: 'class std::vector<astyle::ASBeautifier*>' has no member named 'emplace_back'|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp|2300|error: 'class std::vector<int>' has no member named 'emplace_back'|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp|2530|error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp|2729|error: 'class std::vector<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*>' has no member named 'emplace_back'|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp|3009|error: 'class std::vector<std::vector<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*>*>' has no member named 'emplace_back'|
C:\Users\Win 1809 UEFI\Desktop\qgis\external\astyle\ASBeautifier.cpp|3010|error: 'class std::vector<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*>' has no member named 'emplace_back'|
```

Comment: Welcome :) Which IDE, what was the used command... ? all those details count for those who could help you.

Comment: i used codeblocks ide

Comment: Please mention that in your question with the used command :) My comment was to help you get your question clarified and hopefully answered and avoid being rejected by moderators.

Comment: Welcome! Have you looked at this guide by any chance? http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.github.com/qgis/QGIS/master/doc/INSTALL.html